# libGDX about OrthographicCamera

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, orthographic

I'm trying to do a game like Mega Jump.

Now I have a problem: I have no idea how to get on all devices the same number of columns for items. And how to get the player get to the opposite of the screen if he reaches the screen end.

I'm working whith a OrthographicCamera and box2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for all devices you could use [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) and for the screen end you should calculate the dimensions(Gdx.graphics.getWidth or Gdx.graphics.getHeight). The player should be actor so create a stage and a group, add group to the stage and actor to the group. Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the awser. Do you know any good tutorials for Viewports?

Comment: regarding viewport you can go through this http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx

Comment: for video of same tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ml-XXQaN0hc&list=PLS9MbmO_ssyCZ9Tjfay2tOQoaOVoG59Iy&index=8